# Add an excel column header to single header using c sharp

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to add a couple of new columns to an excel file.  I can add the column pretty easily, but I can't figure out how to add a column header to the excel file.  How on earth do you add a column header to a newly added column?  Here is how I add 3 new columns to a An excel worksheet.

```
    Range rng = (Range)wkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

        rng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
                                XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
        Range rng2 = (Range)wkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

        rng2.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
                                XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
        Range rng3 = (Range)wkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

        rng3.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
                                XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
        wkSheet.SaveAs("C:\\Code\\UPMC\\ISD\\EADIS\\UPMC.ISD.EADIS.ACO.ACOBackLoad\\App_Data\\test", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Headers are just data in X1 where X is the column code.

Comment: That is what I figured.  But I don't understand how you can access the Column objects and change or set the value to something else.  I can't figure out if it is in the range object, the worksheet objeect or what?  Is there some property that I can set like  wksheet.Column or someething like hat?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to any cell like so (this just writes to the "header" as an example):

```
// Type _ = Type.Missing;
wkSheet.Range["A1", _].Value2 = "Heading 1";
wkSheet.Range["B1", _].Value2 = "Heading 2";
wkSheet.Range["C1", _].Value2 = "Heading 3";
```